# How make a page fit on any screen with any orientation

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a web site than must be visible on any screen and any device, and I saw this site the other day.

Inspecting the page with the developer tools of google chrome and "emulating" the width and height of devices I saw that the page fits to any resolution and orientation.

[Image on landscape and as an iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV20m.png)

[Image on portrait as a Samsung device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoM0z.png)

I want to know how to get this without struggle too much with css.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Also I viewed the site from my phone a Samsung galaxy S3 Mini and it fits perfectly to the screen.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Google "Responsive Web Design" to get started. There are many CSS frameworks that will make your life easier: "Zurb Foundation" and "Twitter Bootstrap" are some popular choices

Comment: Outside of CSS frameworks which help, I usually stick with CSS media queries. [W3 docs](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: @dan08 I tried to work with Skeleton but I didn't get the same results, if you know a better framework to work with I will appreciate your suggestion :)

Comment: @Manu - Try [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was about to try with that,  but the client refuses to accept bootstrap :(

Comment: @Manu - Get a new client? But seriously, *why*?

Comment: I will, he refuses because he doesn't want to load the libraries remotely even when I told him that all the libraries are downloadable and can be stored on his server.

Comment: All the cool kids are using Bootstrap these day. [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) is comparable if the client will accept that.

Comment: @dan08 I will try with that, but any of you know if exists a workaround than I can apply right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to make this answer as helpful and to the point as I can:

You will need to spend a few hours reading all you can grab on responsive web design and development, only after that should you begin to explore the right tools to make your CSS life easier.

A lot of what you in responsive development do also depends on your application. To make things *simple* you should begin using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. Any libraries you use must be related directly with any of these languages.

A big rule of thumb is: always try to do responsive development with CSS, but if you cannot for a *good reason*, then and only then should you rely on JavaScript. If you did not learn why this is important after reading the first paragraph of my answer, then you should spend more time going over responsive web design and development (it's worth it!).

As you will find out, there are many techniques and CSS libraries for making responsive web design. A guideline I can give you is: You can learn to make your own responsive development, which in practice leads to leaner code and it will also helps you understand how more robust libraries do it (such as **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)**, among others).

1. Learn and understand **[media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)**.
2. Learn about **[advanced CSS contepts](http://sass-lang.com/guide)** such as mixins and how you can combine them with #1 to make your coding life easier.
3. Learn all you can about **[grids](https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/)** and **[fluid grids](http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids)**, then look at (today's) modern concepts such as **[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)** which will help you with your individual and global layout. Make sure you can do it yourself! (it's not a big challenge, take it one small step at a time, do some tutorials).
4. Begin to dive into some neat CSS frameworks, such as **[Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)**, **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)**, **[Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/)**, among many others. It is imperative you take time to understand *how* they can help you, *what* they can do for you, *extract* only what you need (example: I only need to use the grid system), *are* they community driven? (it is important not to rely on obsolete tools).
5. Do not forget your good friend JavaScript (and the plethora of frameworks you can use with it). Be sure to compliment any behavior you cannot achieve with CSS to achieve your responsive behavior, **not** the other way around.
6. Last but *definitely not least* is cross browser compatibility: once you go deep enough in CSS you tend to forget to always use cross browser compatible techniques. This takes plenty of  - do it yourself - research, but it is not terribly difficult, simply stick with what works for you and for your implementation.

So... only after you have done some reading, played with code and begin to find roadblocks, should you come back here and start asking as many questions as you like. That way we, the community, can assist you properly.

Good luck!

P.S.: Here is a little fun article to get you started: **[Holy Grail Layout](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)**

Comment: I found some helpful articles in your suggestions, I will try to use another frameworks in further projects and find another clients :D thank you very much for your guide and help guys!